# Can Windows 11 move windows to primary display on connect

Tags: multiple-monitors, windows-11

I have a laptop with an external monitor connected via DisplayPort to a USB-C dock.  I have the external monitor marked as the primary display.  When disconnected from the dock, the laptop's built-in display becomes primary.  So apps open on the primary display - the big external monitor when docked, or the laptop panel when undocked.  (When docked, the laptop display is secondary and basically just shows wallpaper pictures since I don't put apps there.)  If I disconnect from the dock, all my windows move from the external monitor to the laptop display.  So far so good.  When I reconnect the dock, with Windows 10 it would move all the windows from the laptop display to the external monitor, but with Windows 11 it leaves them on the laptop display.  It is as if Windows 10 knew they belonged on the primary display (whichever that was at the time) but Windows 11 thinks they belong to the specific display.  Is there any way to make Windows 11 to behave like Windows 10 (and do so without any 3rd party utilities - I don't want to deal with getting approvals from corporate IT)?

Comment: If you don't need the laptop screen while docked, try setting the project mode (Win+P) to "Second screen only", and everything should get shoved over. If you want the laptop screen, you should be able to just set back to Extend again from there without the windows moving back. There aren't settings to change the overall behavior though that I'm aware of

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Try to check the ***Remember window locations based on monitor connection*** setting under **Multiple displays** in Start > Settings > System > Display.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/multiple-monitor-docking-in-windows-11-de5f5f28-2280-451a-9625-a914c479b6f4